# Replace zero result with 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am calculating the average of passing from close to won. How can I to force any AVG result calculation that is zero to be 1, For example, in AE name its result is zero but i want it as 1

```
SELECT name AS OwnerId,
COALESCE(AVG([Opportunity.NumberOfDaysLivedinClose]),1) AS AvgTimeCtoW
FROM(SELECT
       [Opportunity.NumberOfDaysLivedinClose]
      ,name
       from [QueryExtract].[MLDataSource]
     ) as Opportunity
group by name
```

### MLDataSource Table

```
name    Opportunity.NumberOfDaysLivedinClose
NS     0
NS     1
NS     0
NS     1
NS     0
NS     0
NS     0
NS     8

KB     31
KB     1
KB     53
KB     15

AE     0
AE     0
AE     1
AE     0
AE     0
AE     0
AE     0

AT     46
AT     71
AT     10

F      null
```

Expected Result

```
name      AvgTimeCtoW
AE              1
FS              1
NS              1
KB             25
AT             42
```

Comment: Hint : `CASE WHEN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but just use `case`():

```
SELECT name as OwnerId,
       (CASE WHEN AVG(o.NumberOfDaysLivedinClose) = 0 THEN 1
             ELSE AVG(o.NumberOfDaysLivedinClose)
        END) as AvgTimeCtoW
FROM [QueryExtract].[MLDataSource] o
GROUP BY name ;
```

The subquery is also unnecessary.